# Can someone break down this line so I can understand it?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding how an array of ArrayLists is initialized in Java, can someone explain what's going on in this line of code?

```
edges = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[nodeCount + 1];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it space-by-space. 
`edges` is a variable of type `ArrayList<Integer>[]` 
`=` is the assign operator which assignes the right-hand to the left-hand 
`(ArrayList<Integer>[])` is a cast of a variable to the type.
`new ArrayList[nodeCount + 1]` means we allocate space for an array of `ArrayList` with `nodeCount+1` unknown elements.

This is a very bad way of initializing an array. What it does is it creates an array and makes the elements into Integers.

An alternative:
`edges = new ArrayList<Integer>(nodeCount+1);`

**Explanation:** The `ArrayList` class has a constructor which can specify its length*, this is what I use here. 
**Note:** According to @Rohit Jain, it doesn't specify the length, but the initial capacity.

Comment: Provide alternatives?

Comment: I have added it for you.

Comment: Note the parameter in constructor specifies the initial capaccity. It doesn't fix the length.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create an array whose component type is parameterized type. It's not type safe. Although you can create an array whose component type is raw type, but that won't be type safe either. Consider the following example:

```
List<Integer>[] list = null;       // Declaration is OK
list = new ArrayList<Integer>[5];  // Compiler error: Generic array creation
list = new ArrayList[5];   // Compiles fine. But not safe. Gives warning
```

Suppose you created an array of raw types. Let's see what can be the implication:

```
List<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList[10]; // Not type safe

Object[] objArr = list;   // We can assign List<Integer>[] to Object[]

// We can add even ArrayList<String> in Object[]
// This will successfully compile, and run. 
objArr[0] = new ArrayList<String>() {   
    {
        add("rohit"); add("jain");
    }
}; 

// Here's the problem. It will compile fine, but at runtime will throw 
// ClassCastException
Integer val = list[0].get(0);
```

Alternative is create a `List` of `List`:

```
List<List<Integer>> edges = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

**Suggested Read**: -

[Angelika Langer Generic FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html):

- [Can I create an array whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?)
- [Can I declare a reference variable of an array type whose component type is a concrete parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20declare%20a%20reference%20variable%20of%20an%20array%20type%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation)

Answer (score 1):

In the above line you are creating an array of `ArrayList`, you could replace `ArrayList` by a more simple type to help you to understand, e.g. an array of String:

```
edges = (String[]) new String[nodeCount + 1];
```

`nodeCount + 1` corresponds to size of the array. The array can't have more than this number of elements.

Note that using an array of a parametrized `ArrayList` is quite strange and prone to misunderstanding and errors. I would use a `List<List<Integer>>` here, e.g.:

```
edges = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

this line defines an array, like any other array out there: exampe `new Object[0]`, `new String[0]`, ...

and just like any other array, the values will be initiated with the null value. for primitive types is that '0', for objects/classes is that `null`.
so you should initiate the different arraylists before using it like:

```
edges =  new ArrayList<Integer>[nodeCount + 1];
for(int i=0; i<edges.length; i++){
    edges[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does *not* initialize an ArrayList -- it initializes an *array of ArrayLists*:

- `new ArrayList[nodeCount + 1]` = create an array of `ArrayList` objects with `nodeCount + 1` slots
- `(ArrayList<Integer>[])` = cast it to an "array of `ArrayList` objects which in turn may only contain `Integer` objects". This is needed because the array declaration syntax of java apparently can't handle generics (just tried it -- I never needed this before).

It *could* be a misunderstanding, and the writer actually wanted to initialize one `ArrayList` with a capacity of `nodeCount+ 1`. The correct code for that would be

```
edges = new ArrayList<Integer>(nodeCount + 1);
```

Actually the capacity parameter is just an optimization, since `ArrayList` objects grow automatically as needed. But if you already know how many entries you need, the List can be created with enough capacity from the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ArrayList[nodeCount + 1]
```

create a new array of ArrayList, its length is nodeCount + 1;

then

```
(ArrayList<Integer>[])
```

is a cast operation, it casts the array you just created into an array of `ArrayList<Integer>`